# How to rebase so your branch comes from main?

Tags: git, gitlab, rebase

I stupidly started a branch that didn't come from main but from the branch I was working on just before. I only realised it after creating a merge request and after all the changes were done.

I only ever used git rebase during a merge. How can I use it to have a clean merge request ?

Thank you !

Comment: It can be easily done with `git rebase wrong-base-branch my-branch --onto desired-base-branch`.